# Loop through all elements except the last one

Tags: jquery

How can I change each element, but leave the last one just the way it is?

```
jQuery(".diaryevent .field-name-field-category .field-items .field-item a")
.each(function(e) 
{
  var text = jQuery(this).text();
  jQuery(this).html(text + ',');
});
```

Where I need to add e.g. `not(":last-child")` or `:not(:last-child)`

Comment: `jQuery(".diaryevent .field-name-field-category .field-items .field-item a:not(:last-child)"){....}`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vuwzo4bo/ here (I need to add comma on every field except last)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No need to loop using each. With the right selector you can select all the element except the last one.

```js
jQuery(".field-name-field-category > .field-items > .field-item:not(:last) > a")
.text(function(_, text) {
  return text + ',';
});
```

```css
/* Just to see the commas better :) */
a { text-decoration:none;color:#333; }
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="field field-name-field-category field-type-taxonomy-term-reference field-label-hidden">
  <div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even"><a href="/category/business" typeof="skos:Concept" property="rdfs:label skos:prefLabel" datatype="">Business</a>
    </div>
    <div class="field-item odd"><a href="/category/code" typeof="skos:Concept" property="rdfs:label skos:prefLabel" datatype="">Code</a>
    </div>
    <div class="field-item even"><a href="/category/training" typeof="skos:Concept" property="rdfs:label skos:prefLabel" datatype="">Training</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

according to the api, jQuery each function's first parameter is the index of the array..

you can compare it with array's length to achieve what you want

```
var arr = jQuery(".diaryevent .field-name-field-category .field-items .field-item a");

arr.each(function(e) 
{
  if(e === arr.length-1) {
      return;
  }
  var text = jQuery(this).text();
  jQuery(this).html(text + ',');
});
```

fiddle : jsfiddle.net/Lgwtcdzs/1

Comment: Not working...can you try here your code? jsfiddle.net/vuwzo4bo

Comment: not working because jQuery was not defined in the fiddle, also your selector missed a '"' in the end. look here http://jsfiddle.net/Lgwtcdzs/1/ (sorry forgot to save the changed fiddle the first time)

Comment: I edited the answer because I forgot to save the changed fiddle. Now It works

Comment: It worked! I love this solution because the array I get from an external function. Thanks!